# Android Studio: adb rejected shell command (getprop) closed

Tags: java, mobile, emulation

I have been dealing with this error for a week when I`m trying to emulate my app using virtual device in android studio.

> Adb rejected shell command (getprop) closed

I have tried updating SDK according to the device, restarting it but none of those helped at all. I searched but did not find any answers that deals with this specific error.

Some clue would mean great help. Thanks.

( A humble request, if you do not like the question please downvote but still do not use abusive words )

Comment: I have the same problem but unfortunately Google has no answer for bugs. They just release new Android versions and of course compilers! Sometimes they introduce Kotlin as a replacement for JAVA. While Kotlin is a copy of JAVA with definitely more bugs. I would say release one stable Android OS and compiler instead of very problematic ones. Better to learn from Microsoft in this aspect.

Comment: well said @saeedkhalafinejad

Comment: I faced this issue today, and managed to update the android studio via Help menu, which resolved this problem. After the update, when prompted to import config, click Do Not Import and continue with fresh upgrade.

Comment: I have been dealing with this error only when I`m trying my app using in real mobile.  The same mobile used to be OK in the same notebook android studio.  It is still OK for now in same notebook for virtual device. The same mobile is OK in other notebook android studio.